# How to learn Survival Mode maps in MW3?

Tags: xbox-360, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I want to explore Survival Mode maps, are there ways I can do it like split screen or Team Death Match?

Comment: Is this console or PC?

Comment: Xbox Console...

Comment: Good catch, @Bora that does make a difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the Survival Mode maps are the same maps that appear in MW3's multiplayer. If you want to just walk around the map unopposed, simply start a local game with that match and walk around. However, simply knowing the maps isn't enough - until you fight enemies on the map, you don't really get a good feel for sight lines, blind spots, flanks, etc. But yes, you can explore them on your own.

To start a local match select "Multiplayer" from the main screen:

[image]

Then select "Split Screen" (X360/PS3 only; if on PC, you're out of luck exploring the maps):

[image]

Then set up the match and you can walk around the maps at your leisure!

Comment: What do you mean "local match", Can elaborate more? I have never played multiplayer.

Comment: When playing multiplayer you can play online or locally on your xbox with 1-3 other people.  Start an offline local game with just your self and run around.  You could also go online and create a private match and start it with no one else in the game.  Make sure you edit the game time so you have sufficient time to explore.

Comment: Added clarification to the answer